# Is there an IANA media type for Brotli compression?

Tags: media-type, content-encoding, iana, brotli

For gzip, there is an IANA media type "application/gzip" and an HTTP content encoding abbreviation "gzip".

For Brotli,  there is a content encoding "br".  Is there an IANA media type for Brotli compressed data?  If not,  why not?

pvde

Comment: I'm willing to bet the answe to the last question is " No, because nobody submitted to IANA a proposal to add it".